# Where exactly in your body is "心"?

Tags: words, etymology

Where in your body is [心]{こころ} located?

When people refer to [心]{こころ} do they refer to their heart or brain? I assume heart as the literal translation, but I've heard both so was wondering what the answer is.

For example, there is the expression `[心]{こころ}に[浮]{う}かぶ` which seems to me like it would be referring to your brain rather than your heart, is there a distinction between this usage and other usages?

**CLARIFICATION**

I realize the [心]{しん} can refer to your heart, as in [心臓]{しんぞう}. However, my question is about the word こころ not しん.

Comment: Is your question "where 心 is" or "what is 心"?

Comment: @Chris: `where 心 is` is my question.

Comment: @JesseGood: Please clarify. Is your question about the word kokoro or the word sin?

Comment: @Dono: Sorry for the confusion (edited), sawa's answer is about the meaning, however, my question is not about the meaning, it's about the location of こころ in your body.

Comment: "Where's your soul"? I think once we've established that こころ doesn't refer to an internal organ or a part thereof, the question is meaningless (or at least philosophical and therefore off-topic).

Comment: @dainichi: If こころ has the exact same meaning as the English word "mind", I think no one can argue that it is not located in your brain.

Comment: こころ sounds to me more like きもち or 感情 (feelings?) than 精神 or 考え... But こころ is also often used to mean 精神/考え depending on the context, like in こころの病気

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two meanings. As a body part, it means the heart. In the other meaning, it means the mind.

**Edit to match the edited question**

こころ "mind" is an abstract notion. By now, people believe that the location of the mind is the brain. However, that is not included in the meaning of こころ. Within the (not necessarily correct) world where this definition belongs to, there is no real object that corresponds to こころ. It has no location.

Comment: `As a body part, it means the heart`: Could you provide a reference for that claim?

Comment: I do not know of an external reference other than my native knowledge.

Comment: For example, [this reference](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/77985/m0u/) has no definition for the body part.

Comment: That is because the entry you are looking at is こころ instead of 心.

Comment: The answer from Chris was good also, but I decided to select this answer because of the sentence: `However, that is not included in the meaning of こころ.` Also, I would like to point out the one difference between the English word "mind" and こころ is that "mind" *includes* the meaning that it originates in the brain (although there are other differences also).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the actual location of 心 is not really clear. But there are a few places where most people thought.

Based on [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BF%83), the Chinese thought it was located in 心臓、腹部、or 胸部.

Possibly it might be similar to asking "where is your spirit in your body?". That's a hard to answer question and has brought forth a multitude of study, so I'd guess 心 would as well.

I wonder if 「心に浮かぶ」 would be referring to your "mind" more so than "brain".

Comment: Thanks that wikipedia article was very helpful. From what I grasp, originally 心 was thought to be located in the heart (hence the etymology) and in modern times it is considered to be connected with the brain.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [gogen-allguide page for `腹`](http://gogen-allguide.com/ha/hara_karada.html), In present times it's thought one's `心` is located in one's `胸` (chest), while historically it was thought that one's `心` was situated in the `腹` (abdomen), which is also the reason why `腹` is often used to mean feelings/emotions (`腹が立つ` might be one example of this.)

The [page for `心{こころ}`](http://gogen-allguide.com/ko/kokoro.html) also states that the reason 心 can mean "mind" etc is because it was thought in Chinese that the operation of one's mind and one's heartbeat were linked. It also states that unlike the `漢語` (word of Chinese origin) `心{しん}`, after the middle ages `心{こころ}` lost it's meaning of the internal organ.

As with `私の胸の中` and `私の心の中`, I think `胸` can sometimes be used in place of `心` (and vice-versa), but I don't necessarily think they always have the same nuance. In your example, I think `心` can be replaced with `胸`, as there's both [`心に浮かぶ`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E5%BF%83%E3%81%AB%E6%B5%AE%E3%81%8B%E3%81%B6/UTF-8/) and [`胸に浮かぶ`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E8%83%B8%E3%81%AB%E6%B5%AE%E3%81%8B%E3%81%B6).

Comment: Amusing data points: in Okinawan, [チム](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN21044) can mean "heart/spirit/mind", but refers to the liver (肝【きも】)! The same is true in Malay, viz. [hati](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hati).

Answer (score 1):

Heart is 心臓, brain is 脳. 心 refers to your mind. This is not any part of the body.

ps: In restaurant, you often say こころ for animal's heart. I don't know why though.

Comment: I think I read ハツ more than こころ in restaurants. Not even sure I read it once…

Comment: Actually, sawa corrected me on this. こころ is not a body part, but 心 is.